# Matrices with trace zero.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I would like to show that every trace zero square matrix is similar to one with zero diagonal elements.
This question has been asked before, and has had an answer [by *Don Antonio*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158054/complex-matrices-with-null-trace).
And my problem is that I cannot understand the cited paper.
In the [cited paper](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/MathH110/trace0.pdf), (proof 4), one finds the sentence

> Since $\text{Tr}(K) = \text{Tr}(B^{–1}SB) = \text{Tr}(S) = 0$, this step can be 
>   repeated to replace $K$ by a matrix whose every diagonal element is zero ( thereby changing $c$ and $r^T$ ) thus constructing $C$ so that every diagonal element of $C^{–1}SC$ is zero.

**Question**

> I thought that, since $\text{Tr}(K)=0$, we can, by the induction hypothesis, find an invertible $D$, such that $D^{-1}KD$ has diagonal elements $=0$. But how does this enable us to *replace* $K$ by a matrix with zero diagonal elements, at the cost of changing $r^T$ and $c$?

I tried to constuct some matrix $C$ from $D$ such that $C^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}0&r^T\\c&K\end{bmatrix}C=\begin{bmatrix}0&r'^T\\c'&K'\end{bmatrix}$ with $K'$ having zero diagonal elements, but to no avail.
I have tried various choices of $C$, but the result of the multiplication refuses to be of the required form, so I wonder if I am missing something here?
Any hint is well-appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try $$C = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & D\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Thanks very much. This solves all the problems at once. :)