# Show that any zero trace matrix is ​similar to a null diagonal matrix.

Tags: matrices, trace

Show that any zero trace matrix is ​​similar to a null diagonal matrix.

let $A=(a_{i,j})_{1 \leq i,j \leq n} \in M_n(K)$ such that $ \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k,k}=0$ I need to show that  that there is $P \in Gl_n(K)$ such that $B=P^{-1}AP$ such that $diag(B)=(0,...,0)$ diag means coefficients on the diagonal of B .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If $Tr(A)=0$ then $T=R^{-1}AR$ has all entries on its main diagonal equal to $0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1140438/)