# A Linear map A whose trace is 0.

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to know how to prove that there exists a group of base . these base make the matrix of this map is a matrix whose Principal diagonal element is all zero.

Comment: What is a "group of base"? The trace is invariant under base chance and hence cannot be changed.

Comment: @DietrichBurde just a set of base of a linear space

Comment: You mean a "basis" of a vector space. If so, the trace cannot be changed. Take $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \cr 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ or $A=(1)$ etc.

Comment: @DietrichBurde In other words ，how can prove a matrix whose trace is 0 is similar to a matrix whose all diagonal elements are 0 without Jordan standard form.

Comment: You can, before posting this question, just look up here and find a [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1140438/if-tra-0-then-t-r-1ar-has-all-entries-on-its-main-diagonal-equal-to-0).

Comment: @DietrichBurde thank you very much！

Comment: @DietrichBurde can we prove it from a angle of vector space and linear map？